# Добавление логирования по D (SOLID). Как лучше?

Tags: c#, архитектура, логирование, dependency-injection, solid

Насколько я понимаю создавать статическое поле, хранящее ILogger, будет неправильно, так как это влечёт за собой неявную зависимость. Тогда, получается, нужно передавать ILogger через конструктор в классы, которым требуется эта зависимость? Я нашел очень мало материала по этому поводу, не обессудьте, буду рад любому совету или ссылке.
Я очень хочу соблюсти правильную архитектуру, соблюдающую принципы SOLID, я не претендую на правильное мнение, а лишь хочу получить совет. Спасибо!

---

Хотел бы дополнить вопрос. Вот фрагмент кода, в этот класс я передаю ILogger как зависимость, но внутри класса есть еще интерфейсы, тоже переданные как зависимости через конструктор. Мне в их методах понадобится логирование. Получается нужно в каждый метод внедрять зависимость от ILogger? Это представляется не очень красивым, как посоветуете? Лишний код убрал:

```
class PrintCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly IDataExport dataExport;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public PrintCommand(IRepository repository, IDataExport dataExport, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        this.dataExport = dataExport ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataExport));
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public CommandResult Execute(string[] args)
    {
        // какой-то код

        // В методах GetProducts и GetString мне хотелось бы тоже вести лог
        var products = repository.GetProducts(shopId);
        return new CommandResult(dataExport.GetString(products));
    }
}
```

---

Всем большое спасибо за ответы и советы, читаю Марка Симана, скоро дополню реализацией/решением, чтобы как-то подытожить

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Мне в их методах понадобится логирование. Получается нужно в каждый метод внедрять зависимость от ILogger

Не в каждый метод, а в каждый класс, который должен логгировать свое поведение. Логгирование нужно внедрять не в интерфейс, а в реализацию этого интерфейса.

Что именно писать в лог - это ответственность каждого конкретного класса и метода, т.к. в логе вы скорее всего хотите видеть конкретный контекст работы этого метода, и какая-то общая обертка, которая просто будет логгировать факт вызова метода вам этого контекста не даст.

Как именно писать в лог - это ответственность конкретной реализации логгера. Какая именно реализация логгера будет использована - это DI.

Стандартное решение в .NET Core - это вставка логгера через зависимость `ILogger<T>` в каждый класс, который хочет что-то залогировать. [Стандартный способ вставки зависимости для `ILogger<T>` - constructor injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-a-service-that-depends-on-ilogger) (осторожно, там пример кода для исключения factory method, не для constructor injection :)

```
class PrintCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly IDataExport dataExport;
    private readonly ILogger<PrintCommand> logger;

    public PrintCommand(IRepository repository, IDataExport dataExport, ILogger<PrintCommand> logger)
    {
        this.repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        this.dataExport = dataExport ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataExport));
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public CommandResult Execute(string[] args)
    {
        // какой-то код

        // В методах GetProducts и GetString мне хотелось бы тоже вести лог
        var products = repository.GetProducts(shopId);
        return new CommandResult(dataExport.GetString(products));
    }
}
```

Если команды создаете кодом - сделайте Factory, которая создавала бы команду с логгером, или перенесите логгирование самого факта выполнения команды в код, который вызывает `Execute'.

В репозитории и dataExport, добавляйте отдельные зависимости на `ILogger<SomeRepository>` и `ILogger<SomeDataExport>`, соответственно. Логгирование в командах никак не должно пересекаться с логгированием в репозитории по коду. Инстанс логгера прокидывать не нужно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это самый точный ответ. На самом деле, так я себе это и представлял, но не был уверен, что это возможно. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 15):

Если строго следовать принципа SOLID, то следует взять во внимание SRP - принцип единой ответственности.

Логирование - это отдельная ответственность, которой класс команды не должен заниматься. В команде вообще не должно быть логгера.

Вместо этого можно сделать логирующую оболочку (паттерн декоратор).

Убираем из `PrintCommand` логгер:

```
class PrintCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly IDataExport dataExport;

    public PrintCommand(IRepository repository, IDataExport dataExport)
    {
        this.repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        this.dataExport = dataExport ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataExport));
    }

    public CommandResult Execute(string[] args)
    {
        return new CommandResult(...);
    }
}
```

Делаем декоратор:

```
class LoggingCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommand command;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public LoggingCommand(ICommand command, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.command = command ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public CommandResult Execute(string[] args)
    {
        // логируем входные параметры
        logger.Log(/* args */);

        var result = command.Execute(args);

        // логируем результат
        logger.Log(/* result */);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
IRepository repository = ...;
IDataExport dataExport = ...;
var printCommand = new PrintCommand(repository, dataExport);

ILogger logger = ...;
var loggingPrintCommand = new LoggingCommand(printCommand, logger);
```

Далее передаём `loggingPrintCommand` вместо `printCommand` туда, где требуется `ICommand`.

Это легко реализуется с помощью инъекции зависимостей. В книге Марка Симана уделено внимание настройке DI для декораторов.

---

Кроме декораторов для этой же цели можно использовать наследование и инъекцию стратегий. Это три основных способа расширения возможностей классов. Но декораторы удобны тем, что их легко вкладывать один в другой и они дружат с DI.

Однако, в декораторе нужно писать оболочки для всех методов, что утомительно и нудно. На помощь может придти AOP - перехватчики (interceptors), о чём опять же хорошо написано в книге Симана. Рекомендую!

Comment: На самом деле для реальной полезности мне хотелось бы логировать методы зависимостей PrintCommand, а именно: dataExport и repository. Как мне это лучше сделать?

Comment: @Олег - нужно передавать логгер именно в объекты dataExport и repository. Или сделать для них логирующие декораторы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не нужно передавать логгер в другие объекты. это ж в чистом виде зависимость именно dataExport и repository, ее туда должен DI прокидывать, а не вызывающий код :)

Answer (score 10):

Хороший вопрос, практический и хотя мне кажется, что немного отдаёт вкусовщиной (все делают по-разному), но вполне есть объективные вещи, которые стоит учесть при ответе.

Действительно, по строгим классическим подходам а-ля DDD, принципам SOLID гораздо более правильно явно описывать зависимости и передавать на конструктор. Если у вас уже подключен готовый DI-движок, то рекомендую так и поступать.

Насчёт того, насколько строго соблюдать все заветы ООП и DDD -- вопрос зачастую имеет весьма конкретную денежную составляющую: полностью всё делать по книгам может оказаться слишком трудозатратно в человеко-часах и соответственно в стоимости продукта, поэтому этот вопрос хоть и архитектурный, но следует согласовывать ещё и с бизнесом.

Например, я в своих проектах не закладываю уход от Entity Framework. Пробовал когда-то играться с тем, как это правильно делать (если хотите посмотреть в эту сторону, то почитайте Марка Симана Dependency Injection in c#) — но потом понял, что это долго и непрактично. Если потребуется — окей, тогда и стоит делать, а так вот именно этот момент обычно проще сделать не совсем по канону.

---

Update. По поводу дополнения. Нет, в методах объявлять зависимости уже не нужно, раз вы указали на конструкторе. Подробнее — опять отправляю к книге М. Симана, почитайте, там очень хорошо матчасть описана. Единственное, помните также и о первой букве в SOLID: вероятно правильнее говорить об одном публичном "методе", а не о множестве публичных "методов" класса.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это мне как раз и нужно

Comment: Да, у меня во всех зависимостях этого класса по одному публичному методу кроме IRepository - в нем два: GetProducts и AddProducts

Comment: @Олег В репозиториях это нормально, поэтому я и не стал прям жёстко на SRP настаивать. Хотя в принципе от этого можно и уйти - подход CQRS позволяет разобрать на отдельные классы. Вот, например, я подобное приложение выкладывал на гитхаб: https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend

Comment: @A K Спасибо, обязательно ознакомлюсь, звучит интересно