# Обёртка для функций C#

Tags: c#, атрибуты

**Всем доброго времени суток!**

Абстрактная задача с которой столкнулся: имеется класс с набором публичных функций, необходимо расширить каждую эту функцию дописав определенный функционал в самый конец.

С чем непосредственно столкнулся: ряд функций класса формируют ответ определенного единого формата, но необходимо добавить логирование данного ответа, а для этого необходимо дописать по одной строчке в конец каждой функции. И тут я задумался: а бывают ли обёртки в C#? Например, атрибуты, которые вызываются в конце функции, на которую они наложены или ещё что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Встроенных атрибутов таких нет. Но для решения таких задач можно использовать https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Подобное можно сделать с помощью: 1) Паттернов типа декоратора 2) Перехватчиков, встроенных в IoC 3) Аспектами типа библиотеки PostSharp

Comment: Да, бывают. Атрибуты подразумевают использование аспектно-ориентированного программирования, сам перехват управления так и называется intercept. Иногда может использоваться кодогенерация на лету, например при формировании dynamic proxy объектов. Ничем этим заниматься как правило нет смысла из-за сложности реализации и понимания кода, проще вставить логирование в каждый метод. Для большей информации можете глянуть сюда например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c

Comment: Раз уж такой вопрос, добавлю своё: знаю с помощью рефлексии можно получить IL код метода в виде byte[]. Можно ли добавить к этому массиву байтов свой массив байтов в котором будет условно `Console.WriteLine("text")`? Далее, я полагаю, этот массив байтов можно преобразовать в какой-нибудь MethodInfo и вызвать через Invoke?

Comment: Рекомендую книгу AOP in .NET. В ней рассказано и о разных способах АОП: runtime, compile-time, и о разных библиотеках для этой цели.

Comment: Декоратор кажется здесь наиболее простым решением.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220090/184217 - пример логирующего декоратора